# How to edit a file and save it using Python selenium or robotframework

Tags: python, selenium, download, robotframework, ui-automation

I have the following automation scenario.

I want to download an excel file from the browser, open it , save it and then upload it back on the website.

My question is is it possible to edit a downloaded file using python selenium?

Can someone please help me with this. What is the best approach that I could use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is possible, yes.  Apache POI is good for reading/writing excel files.

Comment: There are at least three distinct questions here. Please focus on only one thing at a time.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for your response. Could you please explain a bit how can i include this in my python code?

Comment: @BryanOakley sorry for the confusion but that is my exact 1 question. There are answers for how to download and how to upload a file using python. I will try to edit my question to be exact "Is there a way that I can automate editing a downloaded file using python selenium".

Comment: That's three questions: a) how to download a file, b) how to modify the file, c) how to upload. That's three separate problems.

Comment: @BryanOakley i completely agree wit you. It wasn't clear what is the hurdle for me. I had the download file and upload file part sorted. My biggest concern at this point is to modify that file. I have edited the question too. Thank you again for your response

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and modification again with under code:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  File Upload Download in Robot Framework
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library   OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Verify File Upload
    [documentation]  This test case verifies that a user can successfully upload a file
    [tags]  Regression
    Open Browser  https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload  Chrome
    Wait Until Element Is Visible  id:file-submit  timeout=5
    Choose File  id:file-upload  /Users/alapan/PycharmProjects/Robot-Framework/Resources/Upload/sunset.jpg
    Click Element  id:file-submit
    Element Text Should Be  tag:h3  File Uploaded!  timeout=5
    Element Text Should Be  id:uploaded-files  sunset.jpg  timeout=5
    Close Browser
   
Verify File Download
    [documentation]  This test case verifies that a user can successfully download a file
    [tags]  Regression
    ${chrome options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${prefs}  Create Dictionary
    ...  download.default_directory=/Users/alapan/PycharmProjects/Robot-Framework/Resources/Download
    Call Method  ${chrome options}  add_experimental_option  prefs  ${prefs}
    Create Webdriver  Chrome  chrome_options=${chrome options}
    Goto  https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/download
    Click Link  css:[href="download/sunset.jpg"]
    Sleep  5s
    ${files}  List Files In Directory  /Users/alapan/PycharmProjects/Robot-Framework/Resources/Download
    Length Should Be  ${files}  1
    Close Browser

*** Keywords ***
Verify File Upload
    [documentation]  This test case verifies that a user can successfully upload a file
    [tags]  Regression
    Open Browser  https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload  Chrome
    Wait Until Element Is Visible  id:file-submit  timeout=5
    Choose File  id:file-upload  /Users/alapan/PycharmProjects/Robot-Framework/Resources/Upload/sunset.jpg
    Click Element  id:file-submit
    Element Text Should Be  tag:h3  File Uploaded!  timeout=5
    Element Text Should Be  id:uploaded-files  sunset.jpg  timeout=5
    Close Browser
```

For next explain of the code, you can see in this website: `https://testersdock.com/upload-download-robot-framework/`

Comment: thanks for your response. Could you please share your insight about how can i edit that file using robot framework or python? The download and edit part is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I was able to automate my scenario by using Python append file function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I downloaded openpyxl and used it with load_workbook to write into different columns of the excel sheet and saved the sheet in the end.